# Pandas - Formatting date column of different format in the same column

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to convert a timestamp column to the below format:

Expected output: `2019-05-20 13:25:00`

Given below is how my dataframe is:

```
item, date
item_1, 2019-05-19 22:47:51.722615
item_2, 22/05/19 9:43
```

I tried to do the below:

```
pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S').dt.strftime(
    '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

I keep getting an error `ValueError: time data 22/05/19 9:43 doesn't match format specified`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If possible, remove parameter `format`:

```
df['date1'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date']).dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

If need specify all formats, add parameter `errors='coerce'` for `NaN`s for not matched values, so then use [`Series.round`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.round.html) for final datetimes:

```
d1 = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', errors='coerce')
d2 = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%d/%m/%y %H:%M', errors='coerce')

df['date2'] = d1.combine_first(d2).dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
print (df)
     item                        date                date1  \
0  item_1  2019-05-19 22:47:51.722615  2019-05-19 22:47:51   
1  item_2               22/05/19 9:43  2019-05-22 09:43:00   

                 date2  
0  2019-05-19 22:47:51  
1  2019-05-22 09:43:00
```